# Write command output to a file and to std out/error

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal

I have a command that I run a lot which I like to direct it's output to a file.  I do this like so:

```
runFooBar > output.txt 2>&1
```

Is there a way that I can write the runFooBar output to the file output.txt while still being able to see the output in standard out/error while the command is running?

I run this on Linux and OS X machines.

Answer (score 3):

Use the "tee" command.

```
echo hi | tee ./file.txt
```

The "tee" command takes the standard input and redirects it to both the file specified and standard out.  It's called 'tee' after the t-shaped junction in plumbing (piping).

Comment: Will this write and prints both std error and std out? If not, how would I do that?

Comment: Potentially you could use tee twice; just use the second tee command to pipe standard out to standard error.

Answer (score 1):

The way to redirect both standard output and standard error to the **same** file is:

```
echo Hello 2>&1 | tee some_file.txt
```

This will place both of them into the same file. You may perhaps wish to put them into **separate** files. You can achieve that a Bash feature, [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html), as follows:

```
echo Hello > >(tee standard_output.txt) 2> >(tee standard_error.txt >&2)
```